# C++: vector object interferences with global array of char

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I wrote in C++ a simple interpreter of an esoteric programming language called Brainfuck.
Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/yughias/Brainfuck-Interpreter/blob/main/brainfuckInterpreter.cpp). I don't know why but if I declare vector and a global char array in this way:

```
char memory[128];
vector<int> stack;
```

the program will stuck forever once I try to use the vector object, for example calling the method `stack.push_back(2)` 
In the other way if I declare variables in this way:

```
vector<int> stack;
char memory[128];
```

The program will run correctly. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: No. But given the sensitivity to declaration order, I suspect that `stack` is getting overwritten by `memory` writes past it's actual size.

Comment: You may have some kind of undefined behavior going on in your program. There's no definitive answer with so little information, but one place to look is at any access to `memory` that could perhaps write outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: What does `valgrind` say about your program? Make sure it’s `valgrind`-clean before any further debugging.

Comment: Without looking at this in detail, I can at least say that 128 is way too small for the memory size. 30,000 is the minimum acceptable size, and I tend to use more like 16 million these days.